# Deploying Webpart to SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, web-server

I am unsure how to deploy a SharePoint project solution to a SharePoint site. I thought it was by deploying to the SharePoint server, but is that not enough? Do I deploy to SP and Web server?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2010, on SharePoint server 2010

Note 2: The issue I'm having is that, when I tried deploying my solution file, I can only add one of three webparts....and it's on the Central Administration app. So how do I activate the webpart feature for the SharePoint site such that I can add a webpart to any page on the site? I would find it funny if it's only to a single page.

Note 3: I've managed to deploy it to the correct app....but when I try to retract the solution and install it again, it says it already exists.

Comment: You need to deploy only to sharepoint server? what is the issue you are getting??

Comment: The issue is that, after trying to deploy, I can only add one of three webparts I've developed and only when editing the Central Administration page on the server. It doesn't recognize the site URL of the page I want to add webparts to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Package/Publish (not sure what version of VS you are using) in Visual Studio. This creates a WSP package that can be added to the farm via [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607552(v=office.15).aspx) on one of the SharePoint Servers. After it is added, it can be [installed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534(v=office.15).aspx), again via Powershell.

After it is installed, the feature can be activated on your site. Once activated, you can then add your web part to a web part page. You can also write feature activation event receiver code to do that automatically for you.

Comment: I'll clarify that I am using VS 2010. One of the issues I have when trying to deploy after taking the steps that you've mentioned is that there is only one webpart when I have three in the Feature file. So shouldn't I be seeing three webparts?

Comment: If you double click on Package, are all 3 of your web parts listed?

Comment: package.package in VS? Yep, all three are listed. Same in Feature.feature, and the .cab file of the .wsp solution.

Comment: If you check the Central Admin, System Settings, Manage farm solutions, is your feature deployed to all web applications? it sounds as if the feature only activated on the Central Admin web app.

Comment: Yes, I am deploying to all web apps. Which makes this all the more puzzling.

Comment: And the page says it's deployed to all of them. Yet I can only insert it into Central Admin app; the rest of the apps lack the folder containing the webparts.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized the issue. I'm using a script, and I was specifying the Central App URL the whole time. So I deployed to the actual site/app I want to deploy to, but now it's saying that the solution already exists in the store....even after I removed it.

Comment: You'd need to retract the solution, remove it, then add, and install it and it should clear that  up.